# I am trying to use componentdidmount function

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react,

I am learning react, In this process I tried to create a for componentdidmount forreact. Were I am stuck in the following code

Below is my code

```
import React from "react";
import {Card, Button, Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import addquantity from '../Functions/quantityadd.js';

  const numberOfCards = 100;
  const Home = (props) => {

    componentdidMount(){
        console.log('First this called');
      }

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <Container>
            <Row xs={3} md={4} lg={6}>
            {[...Array(numberOfCards)].map((e, i) => {
                return (
                  <Col className='mt-5' key={i+1}> 
                      <Card >
                          {/* <Card.Img top width="100%" src="/images/companylogo.png" alt="Card image cap"/> */}
                          <Card.Body>
                              <Card.Title tag="h5">Test</Card.Title>
                              <Card.Subtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</Card.Subtitle>
                              <Card.Text>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                                  card's
                                  content.</Card.Text>
                              <Button onClick={() =>addquantity(i+1)}>Button</Button>
                          </Card.Body>
                      </Card>
                  </Col>
                )
            })}
            </Row>
        </Container>

      </div>
    );
  }
  export default Home;
```

I  need to load the data of the product list. so I am using componentdidmount

Can you help me to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is `componentDidMount` not `componentdidMount`,   https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: You can't use componentDidMount in functional components, use useEffect instead.

Comment: To append onto hellogoodnight's comment, see specifically the [timing of effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects). React function components use React hooks (with depdnencies) for handling the component lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

first of all this is "componentDidMount"

And in functional components we use "useEffect" for life cycle hooks and
"componentDidMount" is for class components